# How to determine if an EXIT trap is defined for a BASH subshell?

Tags: bash

Below is a example BASH script.

```
#!/bin/bash

exithdl() { 
    echo "in exithdl subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
}

fun() {
    echo "in fun subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
    trap -p EXIT >&2
    echo "returned from fun"
}

echo "subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
trap exithdl EXIT
trap -p EXIT >&2
echo "$(fun)" >&2
echo "exiting" >&2
```

When executed the following output is produced.

```
subshell=0
trap -- 'exithdl' EXIT
in fun subshell=1
trap -- 'exithdl' EXIT
returned from fun
exiting
in exithdl subshell=0
```

The `trap -p EXIT >&2` command in subshells 0 and 1 shows a EXIT trap defined, but the `exithdl` function only executes after subshell 0 exits. If there a way to determine that `exithdl` will not execute after subshell 1 exits? In other words, is there a command or commands that I could add to `fun` so this function could determine that subshell 1 does not have a EXIT trap?

### Update 1

This update is in response to a comment made by user [suspectus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1827600/suspectus).

In the example below, the function `fun` defines the same EXIT trap as defined in subshell 0.

```
#!/bin/bash

exithdl() { 
    echo "in exithdl subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
}

fun() {
    echo "in fun subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
    trap exithdl EXIT
    trap -p EXIT >&2
    echo "returned from fun"
}

echo "subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
trap exithdl EXIT
trap -p EXIT >&2
echo "$(fun)" >&2
echo "exiting" >&2
```

When executed the following output is produced. Here, the exiting each subshell causes function `exithdl` to execute.

```
subshell=0
trap -- 'exithdl' EXIT
in fun subshell=1
trap -- 'exithdl' EXIT
in exithdl subshell=0
returned from fun
exiting
in exithdl subshell=0
```

Comment: why can't `trap -p EXIT` be used in fun() to check if trap exists?

Comment: @suspectus: In the example, an EXIT trap is defined for subshell 0, but not for subshell 1. The `trap -p EXIT` command shows the exact same output when executed in both subshells. So, I have assumed `trap -p EXIT` can not be used to check if a trap exists for  a particular subshell. I agree that the `trap -p EXIT` command shows the existence of an EXIT trap when executed in `fun`, but not if the EXIT trap will execute when fun returns. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes the EXIT trap executes BUT (I think) when the *script* exits. You get the "exiting" message and then the trap handler message. Is it me?

Comment: @suspectus: I added Update 1 to my question. This is an example where an EXIT trap can execute before the *script* exits. (Note: I did reorder the original example to make it easier to compare with the second example)

Comment: `in exithdl subshell=0
returned from fun` - I get subshell=1 here. [This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/374269/209955) related.

Comment: Or something similar to `trap -p | grep -q 'EXIT' && echo "EXIT trap set"` to test and respond if `trap` is set for `EXIT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When Using Bash 3

The answer depends on the version of bash you are using. For example, my Mac, with macOS High Sierra installed, by default uses `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin17)`. In this case, the problem can be fixed by added parentheses to the command `trap -p EXIT >&2` in function `fun`, as shown below.

```
#!/bin/bash

exithdl() { 
    echo "in exithdl subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
}

fun() {
    echo "in fun subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
    (trap -p EXIT >&2) <--- See Here
    echo "returned from fun"
}

echo "subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
trap exithdl EXIT
trap -p EXIT >&2
echo "$(fun)" >&2
echo "exiting" >&2
```

The resulting output, shown below, no longer shows function `fun` as having a `EXIT` trap.

```
subshell=0
trap -- 'exithdl' EXIT
in fun subshell=1
returned from fun
exiting
in exithdl subshell=0
```

This method also works for a subset of the other traps. For example, this subset includes the `INT`, `QUIT`, `TERM` and `CHLD` traps. However, this subset does not include `HUP` and other traps.

### When Using Bash 4 and 5

I also have Ubuntu 18 and 19 installed in VirtualBox. These operating systems by default are using `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and `GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`, respectively. When the script with the change shown above executes, the result is unchanged from the original output. However, for these newer versions of bash, the problem can be fixed by added a `trap` command before the command `trap -p EXIT >&2` in function `fun`, as shown below.

```
#!/bin/bash

exithdl() { 
    echo "in exithdl subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
}

fun() {
    echo "in fun subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
    trap -- KILL <--- See Here
    trap -p EXIT >&2
    echo "returned from fun"
}

echo "subshell=$BASH_SUBSHELL" >&2
trap exithdl EXIT
trap -p EXIT >&2
echo "$(fun)" >&2
echo "exiting" >&2
```

The `trap -- KILL` command was chosen because the `KILL` trap can not be changed. This results in the same output as shown above. This method also works for the other traps.

### Conclusion

If you want to set a variable (say `exitTrap`) to the command used to define the current `EXIT` trap, then use the script shown below. This should work for bash 3, 4 and 5.

```
trap -- KILL
exitTrap="$( (trap -p EXIT) )"
```